# Set Length, Width, Height OOTB Attributes Using API

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, api

Currently I can only change weight using api not Length, Width and Height. these are out of the box attributes in magento 2.3 as seen in the product panel below.
[image: LWH in Magento 2 Product Config Page]

Price and weight is updated by POST to "http://www.hostname.com/rest/V1/products"

POST body contains:

```
{
"product": {
    "sku": "ProductSKU",
    "price": 99.99,
    "weight": 10,
    "extensionAttributes": {
        "stockItem": {
            "qty": 4,
            "isInStock": true
        }
    }
},
"saveOptions": true
```

}

This works perfectly for changing the price and weight. What line can I add to change the built in Length, Width and Height attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You have use ts_dimensions_length, ts_dimensions_width, ts_dimensions_height in the custom_attributes.

[8] => Array
                (
                    [attribute_code] => ts_dimensions_length
                    [value] => 1.0200
                )

```
        [9] => Array
            (
                [attribute_code] => ts_dimensions_width
                [value] => 0.5200
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [attribute_code] => ts_dimensions_height
                [value] => 0.1500
            )
```